# How to insert hash values into database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

I have a hash like so:

```
{
 "feid"=>32, 
 "fid"=>11, 
 "fipl"=>11, 
}
```

I want to save each value to it's respective column in a database.

I know I can do the following

```
    record = Metric.new
    record.feid = hash['feid']
    record.fid  = hash['fid']
    record.fipl = hash['fipl']
    record.save
```

But my hash is a lot longer than 3 elements and there must be much more simple way!

Comment: Do `record.update_attributes(hash)`... if record already exists,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is. For new record (creation, assignment and saving to db in one go):

```
record = Metric.create(hash)
```

Creation and assignment without saving:

```
record = Metric.new(hash)
```

For existing record, assigning and saving:

```
record.update_attributes(hash)
```

and assignnment without saving:

```
record.assign_attributes(hash)
```

Note:

Saving methods (`create` and `update`) will not raise an exception if saving fails (e.g because of failing validation). Saving fails quietly. If you want to get an exception when this happens, use banged versions: `create!` and `update_attributes!`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried record = Metric.new(hash) but I wondered why it wasn't inserting into the db. I understand why now :p

Comment: Just as a little extra comment, as well as `obj.assign_attributes(hash)` you can do `obj.attributes = hash`: the two are equivalent but the latter may be syntactically preferable in some contexts.